# Manipulate pixels using Minimagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

Is there a way to manipulate pixels and create or modify the manipulated image to reflect the changes made to the pixels ?

Minimagick only provides a `get_pixels` method.

Should I convert the array to a string and use the `import_pixels` method ? but then, how can I reconvert the pixels to a blob ?

Comment: In what way do you want to manipulate pixels? Please be more clear about that. If you want to change a pixel's color, you can draw over it with a point primitive.

Comment: I need to change the RGB of pixels. To create image filters for example.

Comment: Are you doing it pixel-by-pixel? There are other commands to modify an image's color in a global way. Are you trying to create an image from scratch pixel-by-pixel to make a filter? In command line ImageMagick you can create a text file in txt format and convert that to an image. Also commands such as -morphology convolve allow you to create a filter and apply it from individual values for the kernel elements. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you should use the `import_pixels` method. Here's a full example:

```
# get pixels
img = MiniMagick::Image.open("image.jpg")
pixels = img.get_pixels

# transform pixels
reverse = pixels.map(&:reverse)

# save pixels
blob = reverse.flatten.pack("C*")
img = MiniMagick::Image.import_pixels(blob, img.width, img.height, 8, "rgb", "jpg")
img.write("reverse.jpg")
```